# XML load in actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript, rss

I am trying the basic XML parsing code from the adobe documentation..

I tried it with several RSS feeds I plan to use, many of large websites..

one worked, the others returned status -10, status: -10 (An end-tag was encountered without a matching start-tag.)

the thing is, these are big sites, there is no way all of their feeds are malformed...

plus, I checked briefly the XML structure, and checked it with an XML syntax checker (Notepad++) and it came out correct..

so why is flash treating these as malformed ? how can I solve it ?

http:// rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml

this doesn't work, and other don't as well from other sites, some other links do work.

I made some progress, I found that loading this rss url,

via a browser gets me the right content, but when I try it  in Orbit download manager, I only get six bytes! which are

```
</rss>
```

maybe this is what flash sees as well ?

what could be the reason for me getting only partial content ?

please help...

```
var my_xml:XML = new XML();
my_xml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean) {
    if (success) {
    if (my_xml.status == 0) {
        trace("XML was loaded and parsed successfully");
    } else {
        trace("XML was loaded successfully, but was unable to be parsed.");
    }
    var errorMessage:String;
    switch (my_xml.status) {
    case 0 :
        errorMessage = "No error; parse was completed successfully.";
        break;
    case -2 :
        errorMessage = "A CDATA section was not properly terminated.";
        break;
    case -3 :
        errorMessage = "The XML declaration was not properly terminated.";
        break;
    case -4 :
        errorMessage = "The DOCTYPE declaration was not properly terminated.";
        break;
    case -5 :
        errorMessage = "A comment was not properly terminated.";
        break;
    case -6 :
        errorMessage = "An XML element was malformed.";
        break;
    case -7 :
        errorMessage = "Out of memory.";
        break;
    case -8 :
        errorMessage = "An attribute value was not properly terminated.";
        break;
    case -9 :
        errorMessage = "A start-tag was not matched with an end-tag.";
        break;
    case -10 :
        errorMessage = "An end-tag was encountered without a matching start-tag.";
        break;
    default :
        errorMessage = "An unknown error has occurred.";
        break;
    }
    trace("status: "+my_xml.status+" ("+errorMessage+")");
    } else {
    trace("Unable to load/parse XML. (status: "+my_xml.status+")");
    }
};
my_xml.ignoreWhite = true;
my_xml.load("http://rss.walla.co.il/?w=/6/4002/0/@rss");
```

Comment: try loading it with URLLoader in actionscript-3 and check the loaded content.